# Subtraction Is Not Returning Correct Value

Tags: c#, subtraction

I'm only making this subtraction:

```
float w = 2.3f;
Console.WriteLine(w - (int)w);
```

Returns:

```
0,29999995
```

How can I fix this problem I need correct value of 0.3

Comment: Use `decimal` type.

Comment: Obligatory [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Basically, multiply by operands by 10, divide the result by 10 (or whatever precision you need).

Comment: @Oliver Same problem with decimal and double too.

Comment: @SarperMakas: Sorry, with `decimal` this doesn't happen: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yvHGMb